# Localization: Do SEs consider it duplicate content if URL doesn't change when switching cultures?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, localization, seo

I have my company's website (Visual Studio / vb / asp.net 4.0) localized in 9 different languages, and they all work great.  When you're on, for instance, about.aspx, and you switch to Russian or Swedish, it stays on about.aspx and doesn't add a querystring to the end of the URL; it just changes the page's text to that language.

Will the major SEs like Google, Yahoo, etc., consider this duplicate content for SEO purposes and if so, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There's no need to create special URLs when developing a multilingual website. Nonetheless, your users might like to identify what section of your website they’re on just by glancing at the URL

and

> If you’re going to localize, make it easy for Googlebot to crawl all language versions of your site. Consider cross-linking page by page. In other words, you can provide links between pages with the same content in different languages

Source: [GoogleWebmasterCentral](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html)

...could be considered a bit contradictive? :/

Comment: Thanks Stefan.  I have a drop down box in the left column so users can switch languages, even after they started off with their first language, at any time in my master pages, so I think that addresses what you said about the googlebot and yahoobot.  Thanks for taking the time to respond -- much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

By Internet protocols, a URL is a locator for a resource, and search engines operate on them and expect them to identify a resource worth indexing. So if a particular URL refers to content that is substantially different when accessed at different times in different contexts, it is treated as one page with strongly mutable contents.

So you should ensure that essentially different versions have different URLs. If the only difference is in the query part, that’s normally OK, but it is safer that the URLs differ in some other way; customarily, the language code is one component of the URL.

I wonder how the different versions can be accessed if they lack separate URLs. It is *possible* of course, e.g. using cookies or POST requests, but not wise——and search engines probably won’t find the versions if they are not accessible via normal links, or something very similar.

Comment: Hi Jukka.  I really don't know how they're accessed ith different URLs.  I just followed MSDN's instructions on implicit and explicit localization.  When you click a language, it accesses a separate resource file in the apps_global directory, based on the CommandArgument (en, de, es-mx, etc.).  I think that tells the server which .resx resource file to access and display the page with, so the URL never changes, but the resource file used to page the display does.  So the contents might be seen as mutable.  I have to look into that.  Thanks for taking the time to respond, and for your input!

Answer (score 1):

I presume the localisation is stored via cookies?

As bots don't do cookies they have no way of seeing any of the localised versions, they will only see the language you use by default.

So it's not duplicate content as the bots can only see one version.

If you use IP to detect location and language then Google will always come from the USA and only see that version of the page.

If you want each localised version indexed then it has to have it's own URL.

I'd also consider adding canonical tags that indicate the other languages/locations available for a specific page.

Comment: Hello Tiggerito.  Yes, I'm using cookies, so that puts some concerns to ease.  When you suggested "I'd also consider adding canonical tags that indicate the other languages/locations available for a specific page.", that is an excellent suggestion, and I'm going to look into how to make canonical tags.  I see Stack Overflow has canonical tags.  That's a great suggestion, and I'm going to look into it ASAP.  Thanks a bunch for the knowledge, Tiggerito!